# How do I register on swik.net?

Tags: website

I may be missing something - but I can't for the life of me find a way to register on the site swik.net - am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is in anyway appropriate for this site BUT:

If you go to their [login page](http://swik.net/?register), the register form is there, but hidden.  Use firebug or Chrome Inspector to edit the .readonly style which will show a big link that says "Or create a new account".  Click on that and it will show the form.  I didn't test it, so I don't know if it's working.

Comment: It didn't work - but thanks - its the closest I came!